# Do you always need to close a new PDDocument object?

Tags: java, pdfbox

do you only need to close a PDDocument after a load/save operation or with every new PDDocument object that is made(fe. when doing merge/split/... operations)?

Let's say, for example, that I have 3 PDDocuments which I loaded from bytearrays:

```
PDDocument pdf1 = PDDocument.load(bytearray1);
PDDocument pdf2 = PDDocument.load(bytearray2);
PDDocument pdf3 = PDDocument.load(bytearray3);
```

Say that I then merge these 3 pdfs into one PDDocument:

```
PdfMergerUtility merger = new PdfMergerUtility();
PDDocument mergedPdf = new PDDocument();
mergedDocument.appendDocument(mergedPdf, pdf1);
mergedDocument.appendDocument(mergedPdf, pdf2);
mergedDocument.appendDocument(mergedPdf, pdf3);
```

I close the 3 pdfs:

```
pdf1.close();
pdf2.close();
pdf3.close();
```

But must I now also close the mergedPdf or is this not needed?

```
mergedPdf.close(); // is this needed?
```

Comment: It's suggested to close the document at the end of all operations. Do you see any reason not to close it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close all `PDDocument` objects when done with them, also `mergedPdf`. This is a good practice and it avoids memory leaks. Where possible, use try-with-resources.